# Change the JsonConverter date format for Play 2.5

Tags: json, playframework-2.5, objectmapper

I've tried to configure the `ObjectMapper` for the built-in `play.libs.Json`. I've followed the documentation, however the MapperLoader seems to be ignored.

This is what I do (based on the documentation):

- Create CustomMapperLoader

  `public class JsonMapperLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {
      @Override
      public GuiceApplicationBuilder builder(final Context context) {
          ObjectMapper mapper = Json.newDefaultMapper()
              .setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.ISO8601_DATE_FORMAT));
          Json.setObjectMapper(mapper);
          return super.builder(context);
      }
  }`
- Explicitly load the loader in application.conf:

`play.application.loader = "JsonMapperLoader"`

When I serialize date, it still gives me the time-stamp instead of specified format.

I have several workarounds for this:

1. I set the object mapper during the creation of
   `ApplicationController`
2. I disable the `play.core.ObjectMapperProvider` and enable my `CustomObjectMapperProvider`.

Is there any better alternatives for this issue?

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried the method suggested in the manual (with custom ApplicationLoader). I use another technique. In short: there is a class, which configures the ObjectMapper; the class is injected it in the Module as a singleton.

You can see the full code example [here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/07/customizing-json-mapping-in-play.html).